# dojo.cookie update?

Tags: cookies, dojo

I am new to Javascript and Dojo. I apologize in advance if my question below has an obvious answer.

A cookie is set to be

```
var foo = "abcde";
dojo.cookie("bar", foo);
```

Later foo became foo = "abcdefghijk".

Is it possible to update dojo.cookie("bar") so that it always contains the most updated information of foo (i.e., must not change the cookie name, "bar")?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this:

```
var foo = "abcde";
dojo.cookie("bar", foo);
foo = "abcdefghijk";
dojo.cookie("bar", foo);
```

See example http://jsfiddle.net/JszB7/4/ and read about dojo cookie http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/cookie.html